# How to achive this kind of flow with iCarousel

Tags: ios, icarousel

[image]

For an iOS application , I am using iCarousel for the purpose .
But cant find how to achieve this purticular design.Any help appreciated

More kind of look like rotory type ...But i have to show some images with transparent background and Rotory cannot make it possible

Comment: what have you tried? Which part of this design couldn't you create with iCarousel?

Comment: This pattern i cannot create. About what i have tried, I did try using '- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform' But no luck in achieving this
' Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like cylinder (or maybe it's inverted cylinder, i forgot which is which) in icarousel.

Comment: More of a Rotory if i have more than 10 images...but i got only 6

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `iCarouselTypeRotary` transform, but if you only have six items, use the valueForOption delegate method to set the count at 10 so that the circle is always a fixed size, e.g:

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    if (option == iCarouselOptionCount)
    {
        return 10;
    }
    return value;
}
```